# Add child objects to array of objects after parents object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, addition

I'm sure there are many ways to achieve that but I'm looking for good variant. 
I have array of objects with **child** array of objects. I want in loop change object. Object which has **child** array of objects add this childs next to parent at the same level with index 2, but not delete any object.

```
(63) [{…},
    1:
    PartImage: null
    Qty: 3
    Desc: null
    reference: 2
    child: [{…}]
    id: 49
    notes: ""
    2:
    PartImage: null
    Qty: 3
    Desc: null
    reference: 2
    id: 50
    notes: ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion and implement some traverse function to run through the nodes of your data and reduce them at only one level

```
let data = [
   {
      id: 49,
      child: [
         {
            id: 55
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      id: 50
   }      
]

function reorderData(node)
{
   (function traverse(node, root)
   {
      if (Array.isArray(node))
         node.forEach(n => traverse(n, root))
      else if (node.child) {
         node.child.forEach(item => data.splice(data.indexOf(node)+1, 0, item))
         delete node.child
      }      
   })(node, node)
}

reorderData(data)
console.log(data)
```

Comment: YGilk1,thanks for answer. How to implement traverse function for me? What is node, root ? How to use it with my_obj like this.traverse (my_obj );

Comment: The problem for me is the id: 55 should be second element in the result, not in the end. All child element should go after parent element.

Comment: Answer edited to fit your needs. I replaced the push() (inserting at the end) by a splice() where you can set the insert location.

Comment: I reworked the traverse algo to make it easier for you to implement in your code. Create a reorderData function in the same way and call it with your data as parameter. Once returned, your data should be reordered the way you want.

Comment: YGilk1, thank you very much. Yes,this solution is right for me. You save my time.

Comment: Good to read, thus you can accept it (check beside the question)